# Sync remote branch from remote git server

Tags: android, git, repository

I have mirror all android repository into my local repository, but with new version release I found it it hard to update from upstream.

Here is the detail:

After I mirror android source, my modification is in my own branch my-jb-mr1 on my private server. my-jb-mr1 is branched from aosp jb-mr1.

- master
- ...
- jb-mr1
- my-jb-mr1

Now kitkat is release on aosp, I found I don't know how to update my private server to keep track on aosp. My idea is

1. merge aosp master to my local repository master, then push to my private server
2. branch the code based the branch node on aosp

But this seems does not work. Because the branch on aosp I want to keep track is kitkat-dev and kitkat-release. The master branch on aosp does not include all commits within the target branch.

What I want is to sync from aosp. After sync, the repository is like:

- master
- ...
- jb-mr1
- kitkat-dev
- kitkat-release
- my-jb-mr1

kitkat-release and kitkat-dev should exactly the same with the branch on aosp.

Could any one give me some hint how to handle this case?

Answer (score 2):

Normally the master branch of AOSP will be a superset of the most recent release branch, but I'm not sure that's the case right now and your question seems to confirm that. Don't expect it to be true all the time, especially not right after a release.

To push the Kitkat branches to your server, start by syncing a workspace from the AOSP servers:

```
repo init --mirror -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b kitkat-dev
```

Normally I'd suggest syncing the mirror manifest as described in the [Using a local mirror](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#using-a-local-mirror) part of the documentation, but right now the mirror manifest doesn't contain all gits that were added in Kitkat. I expect them to be added shortly.

When the sync is done, step into the workspace and push the new branches to your server:

```
repo forall -c 'git push ssh://yourserver.example.com/$REPO_PROJECT aosp/kitkat-dev:refs/heads/kitkat-dev aosp/kitkat-release:refs/heads/kitkat-release
```

You can also use wildcards to push *all* AOSP branches to your server:

```
repo forall -c 'git push ssh://yourserver.example.com/$REPO_PROJECT aosp/*:refs/heads/*
```

Comment: I got an error when push branches into my server 
'error: src refspec aosp/kitkat-dev does not match any.
error: src refspec aosp/kitkat-release does not match any.' Anything wrong?