# gerrit default.xml is not reflecting after the init in manifest.xml

Tags: android, gerrit, repo

Hi I set up my Gerrit with for the latest android aosp 5.1.1_r3.

repo init --mirror -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r3

Update the default.xml with the below changes.

```
<remote  name="aosp"
           fetch="ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx:29418/" />
  <default revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r3"
           remote="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/"
           sync-j="4" />
```

I have created a mirror for this version on my AWS instance under /git/ But when i do a :
repo init -u http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r3

The manifest is still showing as below. Does it mean its going to sync from AOSP or from my AWS server?

```
 <remote  name="aosp"
               fetch=".." />
      <default revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r3"
               remote="aosp"
               sync-j="4" />
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently didn't push your change to your server (which is why the manifest file doesn't include your change). However, you don't have to change the manifest in order to sync code. The `fetch=".."` part in the original manifest means that the gits are going to be synced from the same source as the manifest itself.

However, you *do* have to change the manifest if you want Repo to send commits to your Gerrit server when running `repo upload`. Make sure you push your manifest change, e.g. like this:

```
git push ssh://xx.xx.xx.xx:29418/platform/manifest HEAD:refs/for/name-of-your-branch
```

Finally, do not change the "remote" attribute of the `<default>` element. It shouldn't contain a URL but the name of a remote specified in the manifest, in this case "aosp".

Setting up a local AOSP mirror and allowing local code reviews requires some thinking about the branching strategy and how you mirror branches. The following questions discuss this topic:

- [Pushing repo branch to local AOSP mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530585/pushing-repo-branch-to-local-aosp-mirror/19761697#19761697)
- [Create Android server local repository for specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921673/create-android-server-local-repository-for-specific-tag/20935478#20935478)
- [Sync remote branch from remote git server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761462/sync-remote-branch-from-remote-git-server/19762082#19762082)
- [integrating vendor Android changes into aosp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290049/integrating-vendor-android-changes-into-aosp/26292898#26292898)

Comment: Thanks a lot Magnus for the detailed answer. I have pushed the manifest file and its fine now. I have also updated the default remote to "aosp". Yes I need to understand a lot on the branching and mirroring concepts. The links you have shared will be a lot of help. Cheers.

Comment: Sure Magnus. Here are the steps I have followed till now to setup my gerrit. 
1. Created a mirror on AWS with AOSP 5.1.1_r3 branch 2. Added the review in default.xml to facilitate the code reviews. 

Now i am working on 
3. Creating a separate branch other than -b android-5.1.1_r3 to facilitate our developers to work upon and push their changes. I am going through the 4 documents which you have shared. Do I need to understand any other stuffs before I perform these activities? Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: No, I think those documents should cover most things you need to know.

Comment: Hi Magnus, need your help here. I have followed the instruction in the first reference to create a branch in my server. By default i had mirrored with the -b android-5.1.1_r3. But now i need to create a development branch for my team in the server. I did the following changes. 1. git push origin default:refs/heads/mybranch 2. repo forall -c 'git push aosp HEAD:refs/heads/mybranch' this is asking me username and password for every git project. Are the steps correct what i have done?

Comment: Well, it's one way of doing it. As I believe one of the links describe you don't have to branch every single git, but if you do it looks like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: but entering the username and password for all the git repo's is very tedious. Is there a better way of creating a branch ?

Comment: repo forall -c 'git push aosp HEAD:refs/heads/mybranch' is it possible to do something like this : repo forall -c 'git push aosp/* HEAD:refs/heads/mybranch'

Comment: Address the real problem, which is that you have to enter username and password. How to solve that depends on what protocol you're using. Ask a new StackOverflow question for that (but google the problem first).

Comment: I don't understand what `git push aosp/*` is supposed to do.

Comment: Username for 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080': username
Password for 'http://username@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080': password 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/platform/dalvik
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> mybranch
What i was trying to ask you is, for every single project its asking me to enter username and password, which is very tedious. Is there an option to enter once and it does for all the repo's. I am little new to this, so pls suggest.

Comment: Yes, I undestood _that_ but the `aosp/*` stuff didn't make sense. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github. Over and out.

Comment: I was trying to check the available option. Anyway you can leave that! Thanks a lot for the timely help.